# If $f$ is monotone and $g$ is integrable, is $f \circ g$ or $g\circ f$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Given two functions $f$ and $g$ with compact domain (domain of one contained in range of another or vice versa as required) such that $g$ is Riemann integrable and $f$ is monotonous, is $f \circ g$ Riemann integrable? Is $g\circ f$ Riemann integrable?

I know that monotone function is integrable however composition of ONLY integrable functions may not be integrable.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers counterexample please

Answer (score 2):

Take for example $f(x)=1/x$ which is monotone on the interval $(0,1)$ and $g(x) = 1/x^2$ which is integrable on the interval $(1,\infty)$ but $(f\circ g)(x) = x^2$ is definitely not integrable on $(1,\infty)$.

The other way around. Take $f(x) = \log(x)$, which is monotone on $(e,\infty)$, and $g(x) = 1/x^2$ which is definitely integrable on $(1,\infty)$. However, $(g\circ f)(x) = 1/(\log x)^2$ is not integrable.

I am sure there are simpler counter examples, but these are the ones I just came up with.

Comment: Sorry I modified the question little bit after you added the answer. I never thought the possibility of it on open intervals since I had been dealing on closed intervals.

Comment: You shouldnt change the question after getting a correct answer @HashNuke you can ask a new question